# Need to group by month and region and return the sum in Python Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, pandas-groupby

Hi I have a dataset like below

```
region      Month   price

AI        February  8827

AI        April     9000

AI        July      3453

ANZ       February  1714

ANZ       April     2991

ANZ       July      3453
```

I need to retrieve the **sum** for a particular **region** with the months.

for example:

AI 21280(Sum of all months)

ANZ 6444(Sum of only April and July)

need to do this is in python, I have tried using groupby but cant get the months right.

Comment: Hi there and Welcome to Stack Overflow, for reproductibility, could you provide the data(values of variables). Maybe this helps: stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @DanielG: the data is there in the question itself 
AI        February  8827 (this is the 1st row )

Answer (score 0):

You can try [`df.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) along with [`dict-comprehension`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/):

```
>>> {key: group['price'].sum() if key == 'AI' 
     else group[group['Month'] != 'February']['price'].sum() 
     for key, group in df.groupby('region')}

{'AI': 21280, 'ANZ': 6444}
```